# Is there a name for when characters eyes are hidden from the shot when emotional?

Tags: tropes

The eyes of characters in anime always disappear when they're upset or when they're going to get serious.

Is there a name for when a characters eyes disappear like that?

[image: Character's eyes hidden]

Answer (score 3):

I have never known this by a specific name, but the closest you may come to is just ['hidden eyes'](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiddenEyes).

This is usually used to describe someone who is trying to hide their face because they're upset, hurt, not drawing attention to themselves etc. Other terms might be used for characters whose normal hairstyle obscures their eyes, regardless of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese, and even in English, there is a proverb that basically states that eyes speak more than the mouth does.

In anime/manga especially, eyes are drawn as very expressive and are generally indicative of how a character feels or what they're thinking. When you remove that, it adds a layer of mystery about the intentions of a character and by extension the story/events immediately after.

This works extremely well when the character is either going through an emotional turmoil and is about to take a drastic action, or when a character is about to do something entirely unpredictable and introduce a plot-twist. Here's a good example:

[image]

This is Goku RIGHT before his body switches to offensive and he attacks Jiren, transforming into MUI right after. A massive plot-twist to the fight that turns the tables completely.